# Why can't I update a Community Users ProfileID during JIT provisioning via SAML SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

My Attributes:

```
    {"Contact.Account", "001230942830"},
    {"Contact.Email", "theEmail@gmail.com"},
    {"Contact.FirstName", "theFirstName"},
    {"Contact.LastName", "theLastName"},
    {"User.Email", "theEmail@gmail.com"},
    {"User.UserName", "theEmail@gmail.com"},
    {"User.FirstName", "theFirstName"},
    {"User.LastName", "theLastName"},
    {"User.Alias", "theAlias"},
    {"User.ProfileId", _profileID}
```

I can provision a Community user with with a ProfileID, let's say: 00eC0000001GXivIAG.

Why is it that I cannot update the ProfileID to, say, 00e1A00000192sEQAQ, in a another SAML Assertion?

It still logs in correctly, but the profile remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going another route and trying to create my own custom JIT handler, I came across a section in the template JIT code that says you can't update certain fields on the User when also attempting to update fields on Contact or Account.

```
    /*
 * If you are updating Contact or Account object fields, you cannot update the following User fields at the same time.
 * If your identity provider sends these User fields as attributes along with Contact 
 * or Account fields, you must modify the logic in this class to update either these 
 * User fields or the Contact and Account fields.
 */
if(attributes.containsKey('User.IsActive')) {
  String IsActiveVal = attributes.get('User.IsActive');
  u.IsActive = '1'.equals(IsActiveVal) || Boolean.valueOf(IsActiveVal);
}
if(attributes.containsKey('User.ForecastEnabled')) {
  String ForecastEnabledVal = attributes.get('User.ForecastEnabled');
  u.ForecastEnabled = '1'.equals(ForecastEnabledVal) || Boolean.valueOf(ForecastEnabledVal);
}
if(attributes.containsKey('User.ProfileId')) {
  String profileId = attributes.get('User.ProfileId');
  Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Id=:profileId];
  u.ProfileId = p.Id;
}
if(attributes.containsKey('User.UserRoleId')) {
  String userRole = attributes.get('User.UserRoleId');
  UserRole r = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Id=:userRole];
  u.UserRoleId = r.Id;
}
```